# Ubuntu 12.10 not recognizing android phone

Tags: usb, android, samsung

I have a Samsung transform ultra smartphone and I am running Ubuntu 12.10. when I plug my phone in and set it to mass storage mode nothing happens on the Linux end. I was under the impression that it would show up as a device somewhere, but this isn't happening

`lsusb` shows the phone is connected

> Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:f000 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd

and i've tried creating a mount point for it with instructions from this forum post
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=981774 
but have had no success.

Answer (score 1):

I am using samsung galaxy y GT-S5360, to connect your android with ubuntu here is an alternate option

1st. Go to google play and download "Airdroid" and install it on your phone

2nd. Connect your phone with Ubuntu 12.10 using your usb datacable

3rd. Now, go to phone's Settings > wireless & network > Tethering & portable hotspot > usb tethering. Here enable usb tethering.

if your phone is still connected to pc via a data cable you can enable or disable the tethering option. At this point if your mobile is connected to internet then you can also access net on ubuntu but to use other features of your phone go to 4th step

4th. Now, open airdroid in your phone. When airdroid is running it will show you an ip address. just type that ip address correctly on your pcs browser, voila now you can manage your phone directly from ubuntu...

now you can manage, apps, messages, contacts, files, pictures, movies almost anything that is required.

You can use this same technique in windows base pcs too

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
```